# Laravel, Eloquent, insert data to custom database

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have created a custom db connection:

```
Config::set('database.connections.key', array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => $user[0]->db_ip,
   'database'  => $user[0]->db_name,
   'username'  => $user[0]->db_login,
   'password'  => $user[0]->db_passwd,
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
));
```

It works because I can retrive data using ORM:

```
$d = Time::on('key')->find(1);
```

But I cannot insert any data.

I've tried normal insertion by `->save()` and with `->create()` functions.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: it depends on what I've made but most of the times:
cannot find ->save ->create function

Comment: I'm not sure how to perform such insertion.

Comment: It seemed I've found solution...

    $t = new Time();
    $t->setConnection('key');
    $t->id = 2;
    $t->save();

I misses `->setConnection()` in my insertion.